# How to draw a simple 2D grid (non interactive) in PaperJS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an interactive application mockup made with [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/) but it still lacks a small feature. I need to draw a 2D grid (you know... that uniform mesh of lines that repeat endlessly over a surface), it will be used as guides for user interactions when dragging things over the screen (but the grid itself can be completely static).

I just don't know how to implement it in PaperJS. It can't be just a background image since it will be presented in different scales, also I wanted it to be rendered very fast since it will always be visible.

The type of grid I would like to draw is a 2D mesh centered grid, like in the example (a) of this picture:

[image: 2D basic grid types]

Any enlightenment is welcome.

Comment: This seems like an odd question, since Paper.js appears to be a library for drawing vector graphics, and you're asking how to draw a particular graphic.  Did you try making a Path with moveTo,lineTo,moveTo,lineTo,...?

Comment: I might resolve this simply by using another Canvas and positioning it under the PaperJS one (z-index does the trick). Render the grid there as James suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is lines:

```
var drawGridLines = function(num_rectangles_wide, num_rectangles_tall, boundingRect) {
    var width_per_rectangle = boundingRect.width / num_rectangles_wide;
    var height_per_rectangle = boundingRect.height / num_rectangles_tall;
    for (var i = 0; i <= num_rectangles_wide; i++) {
        var xPos = boundingRect.left + i * width_per_rectangle;
        var topPoint = new paper.Point(xPos, boundingRect.top);
        var bottomPoint = new paper.Point(xPos, boundingRect.bottom);
        var aLine = new paper.Path.Line(topPoint, bottomPoint);
        aLine.strokeColor = 'black';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= num_rectangles_tall; i++) {
        var yPos = boundingRect.top + i * height_per_rectangle;
        var leftPoint = new paper.Point(boundingRect.left, yPos);
        var rightPoint = new paper.Point(boundingRect.right, yPos);
        var aLine = new paper.Path.Line(leftPoint, rightPoint);
        aLine.strokeColor = 'black';
    }
}

drawGridLines(4, 4, paper.view.bounds);
```

If you want each rectangle to be a separate Path to hitTest for the individual rectangles:

```
var drawGridRects = function(num_rectangles_wide, num_rectangles_tall, boundingRect) {
    var width_per_rectangle = boundingRect.width / num_rectangles_wide;
    var height_per_rectangle = boundingRect.height / num_rectangles_tall;
    for (var i = 0; i < num_rectangles_wide; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < num_rectangles_tall; j++) {
            var aRect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(boundingRect.left + i * width_per_rectangle, boundingRect.top + j * height_per_rectangle, width_per_rectangle, height_per_rectangle);
            aRect.strokeColor = 'white';
            aRect.fillColor = 'black';
        }
    }
}

drawGridRects(4, 4, paper.view.bounds);
```